# Hide solution files in node_modules from Team Explorer

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

Having moved from bower to npm in an ASP.Net Core MVC project that is under TFVC source control I now have an additional solution appearing in Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 that is in my node_modules folder:

```
.\node_modules\node-sass\src\libsass\win\libsass.sln
```

How can I stop this solution appearing in Team Explorer? node_modules is already in my .tfignore file and that folder/solution is not in source control.

Comment: This may not be possible. AIUI team explorer's solution list is just a listing of all the files ending in `.sln` in the workspace (TFS-VC) or working tree (git).

Comment: As the answer addressed below, simply making the .sln file hidden should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by simply hiding the node_modules folder.

I saw this as a side-effect when I was following instructions [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Oct/30/Excluding-the-nodemodules-Folder-in-Visual-Studio-WebSite-Projects), hiding the folder reduces the load times and memory footprint for Visual Studio as it doesn't try and preparse all the modules.

[image: Only the folder, not subfolders and files!]

As an alternative and a lighter touch @kakusan pointed out that only the solution file needs to be hidden. Be aware that this change may not be kept if NPM for some reason replaces the file.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I decide to simply make the .sln file hidden.